# Using AppDelegate as a singleton

Tags: ios, objective-c, delegates, singleton, appdelegate

I'm using my `AppDelegate` to handle some audio files. I've made it an `AVAudioPlayer` delegate so I can use methods like `audioPlayerDidFinishPlaying`.

I've done it like this:

```
@interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate, AVAudioPlayerDelegate>
```

And then in any `ViewController` I access my `AppDelegate` in the following way:

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```

Everything works fine but I'm getting the following warning:

```
Assigning to 'APPDelegate *__strong' from incompatible type 'id<UIApplicationDelegate>'
```

Comment: You should think very hard whether you really want your AppDelegate to do all kinds of things that have nothing to do with being the delegate for the application. It always seems like a good idea when you do it, and creates a lot of work later on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast it to your `AppDelegate`'s type -

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = (AppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```